# How to select and list multiple items in a checkedlistbox C#

Tags: c#, addition, checked, checkedlistbox

I am wondering how I can fix an error I am experiencing when I try to create a checkedlistbox, load a list into it, then attempt to display all the checked items in another listbox. For example, checkedlistbox1 displays ABC AAC ABB and I checkmark ABC and AAC, when I push a button, I want it to add ABC and AAC to listbox1 but all it gives me is "(collection)"

```
var selected = checkedListBox1.SelectedItems;
listBox1.Items.Add(selected);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate the *CheckedItems* and add each item one-by-one:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems) {
            listBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I checked output types, but seems that checked something wrong. Thanks.